# Spring Boot number of DTOs for external clients

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solid-principles

I have 2 external clients, Client A and Client B that need Order data stored in MongoDB, and I'm trying to understand the proper way to structure a Spring Boot project to give these two clients what they need. They both need similar data except Client A wants a little more data.

**My thought:**

1. Create 2 controllers, one for Client A and Client B. The Client A controller will return OrderDTO_A and Client B controller will return OrderDTO_B.
2. Create 2 services that both inject the Order repository to grab Order data
3. In each service, I will make a call for the Order data using the repository, map the results to the appropriate DTO, and return the DTO to the controller.

Does this sound right? This feels weird to me because I have my Order domain models that get saved to the database. I have a set of DTO models for Client A, and I have a set of DTO models for Client B.

What if I have a Client C? Based on this, I'd have another set of DTOs for Client C. Is this right? It just feels wrong because I have a lot of DTOs that look very similar, but plus or minus a few fields for the specific client.

Comment: You may use a parent class that includes just basics properties of order, then for your other customers, you need to just create a class that implements parent class. Then you can add specific values for that customer.

Comment: Why don't you just stick with only the "a little more data" model? Client B is free to process just the data it needs… If it's e.g. sensitive data you could also work with [Jackson's JSON Views](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html).

Comment: @slauth, I'm trying to give only the data necessary to each client. The Order model contains around 300+ fields, however the clients really only need 100 or less. I've been told that it's best to only send what is needed by clients instead of sending the entire Order data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Client A just needs a little bit more data I would not go with the Controller/Service per Client approach. Stick with one that provides the data that Client A needs. Client B can ignore the part of the data they don't need.

If this is not desirable because the amount of data is large, then you may consider providing a GraphQL endpoint. With GraphQL it is the client that decides which attributes it wants to receive.

Yet another approach could be JSON Views, but I would avoid it if possible because it can very easily become very hard to maintain.

Comment: Ultimately, my concern was giving too much unnecessary data to clients that don't need it. There are clients that need almost every field on the Order. With this solution, I'd essentially just make 1 endpoint that gives the entire Order object and every other client would call this same endpoint for Order data although they only need a third of the fields. Is that not a problem?

Comment: It really depends on the total amount of fields. Let's say you have 10 fields and your Client B only needs 3. I would it is ok since the total amount of data shouldn't be that much. However, let´s say you have 100 fields and your Client B only needs 10. Then maybe you should consider GraphQL endpoint, with which Client B can request and receive exactly the 10 fields it needs.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary of domain can help us to judge do we need a new DTO.

If the `little bit more data` Client A want belong to the same domain Client B already used, we should reuse the same DTO, rather than creating a new one. The DTO is the composition of domain objects to fit in different use cases.

Check this article's advice about the [common mistake](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern#common-mistakes) when using DTO, I found it is very helpful. cheers.